# Laravel preg_match uri validator

Tags: php, laravel

I'm installing some app with Laravel and Vue, and I'm using php 7.3 but laravel runs with 5.6.
Now is giving me an error like:

> preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid range in character class at
>   offset 20

In folder vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Routing\Matching\UriValidator.php

here is the code

```
<?php

namespace Illuminate\Routing\Matching;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Route;

class UriValidator implements ValidatorInterface
{
    /**
     * Validate a given rule against a route and request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Routing\Route  $route
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    public function matches(Route $route, Request $request)
    {
        $path = $request->path() == '/' ? '/' : '/'.$request->path();

        return preg_match($route->getCompiled()->getRegex(), rawurldecode($path));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your web.php try this

```
Route::get('{path}',function(){
 return view('your.index');
})->where('path', '[A-z\d\-\/_.]+');
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer. It would be great if you could explain what your code does. It would help the community much more that way to learn from you!

Comment: I found this solution on github. as far as I understand the route does not match characters in the path. Initially I set it to [path, '*'] , but it did not help.